# What activities can yield marketable items?

Tags: diablo-immortal

So far I only found that some crafted legendary gems are unbound and therefore could be sold.

What other activities can provide sellable items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I found this:

- You can find unbound regular gems in dungeons when playing in group (group of 4 is recommended since it increases chance of gem drop) on at least Hell 1 difficulty (not sure about difficulty, but I personally didn't receive any drops before Hell).
- You can craft unbound legendary gems but only through recipes for crafting random gems for Fa runes.
- You can extract unbound Skill stones from fully upgraded charms. Extraction itself costs 500 platinum, but with current prices of ~1.5k per skill stone (at least on my server) this yield about 1k platinum profit.